# how to insert data in database using database first approach and many to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having 2 table studentmaster and subject they have many 2 many relationship :-

My table structure is :-

[image]

How can i insert data in these table from mvc controller

This is studentmaster.cs

```
public partial class studentmaster
    {
        public studentmaster()
        {
            this.subjects = new HashSet<subject>();
        }

    public int studentid { get; set; }
    public string studentname { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> dob { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> registrationnumber { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<subject> subjects { get; set; }
}
```

This is subject.cs

using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

```
public partial class subject
{
    public subject()
    {
        this.studentmasters = new HashSet<studentmaster>();
    }

    public int subjectid { get; set; }
    public string subjectname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<studentmaster> studentmasters { get; set; }
}
```

This Model3.context.cs

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class studentEntities : DbContext
{
    public studentEntities() : base("name=studentEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<studentmaster> studentmasters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<subject> subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You just fill one or the other with a collection of the given objects, for instance if you save a subject, then add to it a collection of `studentmasters` and save the entity

Comment: i have tried some codes but does not work .....can you provide any code that works

Comment: is there any solution to this availaible+

Comment: Could you show your action code?

Comment: i don't know how to insert data when there is many to many relationship between tables so how can i show my action code

Comment: You said you tried some code, show the code you tried.

Comment: i don't have them now

Comment: how to insert data in database in mvc when table have many 2 many relationship

Comment: Is there any solution availaible to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [EF Code first: Insert Many to many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551760/ef-code-first-insert-many-to-many). Db first or code first doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something similar to:

```
var subject = context.subjects.First(); //just an example of getting the subject
var student = context.students.Find(id); //get the student you want to update
student.subjects.Add(subject);
context.SaveChanges();
return View();
```

If I missed some nuance(s) and this doesn't work I'll edit my post on Monday when I have my source code in front of me.

It is hard for us to know what you are doing wrong when you aren't showing us your previous attempts. It's always better to save your mistakes until you get it right rather than delete them immediately.